# python3: can't open file '.exporter_main_v2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

Has anyone seen or know to tell me what is wrong with the code below?

on `google colab` code:

```
!python .\exporter_main_v2.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path .\models\my_efficientdet_d1\pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir .\models\my_efficientdet_d1\ --output_directory .\exported-models\my_model
```

Output message:

```
python3: can't open file '.exporter_main_v2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B5EA.jpg)

Comment: No such file or directory?

Answer (score 0):

check if the files you are trying to run are in the directory you are currently working on.

Comment: Yes. I am.....google collab environment have a problem with ". \"?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was the backsclash on colab.

corret path is:
python ./exporter_main_v2.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path ./models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir ./models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/ --output_directory ./exported-models/my_model

tks!!!